# How to convert from lazy text to non-lazy text?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am new to Haskell, so this may be a trivial problem. I am seeing an error message that says

```
Couldn't match expected type 'Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text'
with actual type 'Data.Text.Internal.Text'
```

and I think the problem is that the actual type is `Data.Text.Text` and it expects lazy text. How can I convert one to the other?

EDIT:

here is a simplified code that gives this error.

`{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding
import Network.Mail.Mime
import Yesod

data FormData = FormData { dataField :: Textarea } deriving Show

part d = Part {
    partType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    , partEncoding = None
    , partFilename = Nothing
    , partContent = encodeUtf8 $ unTextarea $ dataField d
    , partHeaders = []
    }

main = return ()`

basically I have a yesod form with a textarea input element and I want to e-mail the contents of the textarea.

Comment: Where are you getting the "encodeUtf8" function from?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`toStrict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text-Lazy.html#v:toStrict) from `Data.Text.Lazy` would do what you ask for (convert lazy to strict).

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like he actually needs `fromStrict`. Also note that while the docs show it as `Text -> Text`, if you try clicking them you'll see that they are actually different types from different modules.

Comment: i have hopefully clarified my problem